# Npm install printer - node-gyp rebuild error on Windows 10 x64

Tags: node.js, printing, node-gyp

Been following all the similar posts regarding `node-gyp` rebuild errors on npm install printer and have tried almost all of them.

I Installed VS Community 2015 plus Python plus Win 8.1 SDK plus C++ Redistributable for VS 2015. Set VS version. I have bypassed some of the earlier errors but now I have another. Perhaps I can get advice?

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: What version of node are you running (you can run `node -v` in the command prompt)? Looks like from the documentation, it's only compatible "with node v0.8.x, 0.9.x and v0.11.x (with 0.11.9 and 0.11.13)"

Comment: @abhi from the screenshot we can tell he's running node 6.2.2. Maybe it's not compatible with that version.

Comment: ah, thanks @mparnisari! Frank I would try using one of those versions of node first :)

Comment: redefinition with different type, looks like incompatability among the components to me also (as @mparnisari suggests)

Comment: Thank You Gentlemen. This certainly did help. Well Done.

Comment: I have decided to write my own Windows specific Print Module that calls the VBS scripts that interface with printers. Too many dependencies with this module. I will upload as soon as done and tested